# Negative R2 from GAMM, but not with GLMM

Tags: r, mgcv

I'm running a GAM using the bam function from the mgcv package and I've noticed something a bit peculiar.

In my model I have a single smoothed adaptive spline on the explanatory variable 'ri' (residency index - values 0-1), to account for periods of rapid change in the mean combined with periods of little change, with 3 other categorical explanatory variables. The response variable is count data and overdispersed so I'm using a negative binomial distribution for the model.

```r
deg_test1 <- bam(deg ~ SE_score + s(ri,bs="ad") + sex + species + 
                    year + s(code, bs = 're') + 
                           s(station, bs = 're'), 
                    family=nb(), data=node_dat, 
                    na.action = "na.fail", discrete = TRUE)
```

The results from this make sense but the R2 and deviance explained seem very high for this type of ecological data.

```
R-sq.(adj) =  0.836   Deviance explained = 95.7%
```

I decided to see what would happen if I ran the model without the adaptive spline explanatory variable, and without this variable at all. What I got in both scenarios was negative values for R2.

```r
deg_test2 <- bam(deg ~ SE_score + ri + sex + species + year + 
                       s(code, bs = 're') + s(station, bs = 're'), 
                       family=nb(), data=node_dat, 
                       na.action = "na.fail", discrete = TRUE) 

R-sq.(adj) =  -59.6   Deviance explained = 60.4%

deg_test3 <- bam(deg ~ SE_score + sex + species + year + 
                       s(code, bs = 're') + s(station, bs = 're'), 
                       family=nb(), data=node_dat, 
                       na.action = "na.fail", discrete = TRUE)

R-sq.(adj) =  -0.172   Deviance explained = 45.9%
```

I also tried running it as a linear model and extracting the psuedo R2 using the r.squaredGLMM function from the MuMIn package, with and without the explanatory variable 'ri'. But I didn't see the same pattern and both models had high conditional R2 values.

```r
deg_test4 <- glmmTMB(deg ~ SE_score + ri + sex + species + year +
              (1|code) + (1|station), family=nbinom1(), 
              data=node_dat)

r.squaredGLMM(deg_test4)
                R2m       R2c
delta     0.1909413 0.8117806
lognormal 0.2036411 0.8657733
trigamma  0.1674027 0.7117070

deg_test5 <- glmmTMB(deg ~ SE_score + sex + species + year +
                           (1|code) + (1|station), family=nbinom1(), 
                           data=node_dat)
r.squaredGLMM(deg_test5)
              R2m       R2c
delta     0.1347437 0.8731454
lognormal 0.1392437 0.9023055
trigamma  0.1272597 0.8246488
```

What could be causing the negative R2 from my GAM when it is run with no smoothed splines? And why do the R2 different from the linear model, wouldn't those be equivalents and showing the same things?

A copy of the dataset can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/snia6tsjigdtf1e/node_dat.csv?dl=0)